# What devices will take advantage of USB 3.0?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, usb-3

All I see are USB 3.0 external hard drives. Are there other devices that will greatly benefit from this higher throughput? Are external hard drives the primary device that's pushing USB 3.0? If so, then I don't think there's much advantage for USB 3.0 for most consumers.

Comment: probably flash drives and other storage/transfer drives will be where usb 3.0 is most prevalent at first, but after a while I would imagine that the people who manufacture usb connectors will simply make everything (i.e. printers & scanners) usb 3.0 out of convenience. IMO.

Comment: You probably won't see an "explosion" of devices until it becomes the standard on new PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this [USB 3.0 monitor](http://www.slashgear.com/3m-demoes-usb-3-0-monitor-0989189/) for example. And I'd guess external GPU would also take advantage of it fairly well.

Comment: I wish wireless monitors would become a reality for the consumer, no more video cable.

Comment: please god no more wireless crap ... aren't our airwaves polluted enough already?  i just wish they'd come out with a reasonable standard connector and stick to it.  @moab

Comment: Its going to get allot worse, Obama just opened up more of the wireless spectrum for use.

"President Barack Obama on Monday June 28, 2010 signed a memorandum to nearly double the amount of federal and commercial spectrum available for smartphones and wireless Internet devices. Mr. Obama's action effectively endorses a plan put forward in March by the Federal Communications Commission to free up 500 megahertz of airwaves as part of a broader strategy for improving the U.S.'s broadband infrastructure"

Answer (score 1):

I think external GPUs will also be seen in times to come. A variety of portable notebooks now have CPUs capable of running high end graphics applications/games. In order to keep the portability we need good battery life and this means small screens and low power GPUs, however When these become external it will be an opportunity to replace the desktops we currently rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Recording equipment -- both audio and video -- will benefit from the higher throughput.  The audio world will be especially happy if USB 3 does anything to fix the horrid latency of USB 2.